# Other ways to replace single character

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a simpler way to do the following:

```
def replace(txt,pos,new_char):
    return txt[:pos] + new_char + txt[pos+1:]
```

to do the following?

```
>>> replace('12345',2,'b')
'12b45'
```

Comment: Why cant you use replace?

Comment: I can't think of anything better in the general case. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Note that if you are writing to file your best bet may be to not create the new string and just pass the pieces individually to `your_file.write(piece)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested some solutions to find the best performance,

The tester source code was:

```
import __main__
from itertools import permutations
from time import time

def replace1(txt, pos, new_char):
    return txt[:pos] + new_char + txt[pos+1:]

def replace2(txt, pos, new_char):
    return '{0}{1}{2}'.format(txt[:pos], new_char, txt[pos+1:])

def replace3(txt, pos, new_char):
    return ''.join({pos: new_char}.get(idx, c) for idx, c in enumerate(txt))

def replace4(txt, pos, new_char):    
    txt = list('12345')
    txt[pos] = new_char
    ''.join(txt)

def replace5(txt, pos, new_char):
    return '%s%s%s' % (txt[:pos], new_char, txt[pos+1:])


words = [''.join(x) for x in permutations('abcdefgij')]

for i in range(1, 6):
    func = getattr(__main__, 'replace{}'.format(i))

    start = time()
    for word in words:
        result = func(word, 2, 'X')
    print time() - start
```

And it's the result:

```
0.233116149902
0.409259080887
2.64006495476
0.612321138382
0.302225828171
```

Comment: Care to back it up with some measurements?

Comment: @PavelAnossov I thaught it creates one new string instead of two, No?

Comment: No, it creates the  format string, two slices, and the result. OP's replace creates two slices, a temporary result of concatenation, and the result, So four for four.

Comment: I guess `re.sub()` would also be an option, but it seems there is no faster way.

Comment: @erikb85 `re.sub()` replaces a pattern in string with something else, it's something like `str.replace` but based on RE. So it is not comparable with this `replace` function.

Comment: @MostafaR:  Technically, one *could* use `re.sub`:  `re.sub('(?<=.{%s}).' % pos, new_char, txt, count=1`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Thank you very much, I'm not very familiar with RE. I just checked it's performance, it took about 1.5 seconds.

Comment: @MostafaR:  As expected it's a stinker.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is simpler:

```
>>> txt = list('12345')
>>> txt[2] = 'b'
>>> ''.join(txt)
'12b45'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about "better", but an alternative is to adapt something like the following:

```
>>> ''.join({2: 'b', 4: 'x'}.get(idx, c) for idx, c in enumerate(s))
'12b4x'
```